# Use Chokidar to watch for specific file extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems

I am looking to watch a folder using the nodejs Chokidar
I only want to monitor for additions, deletes of xml files.
I am new to Chokidar and can't figure it out.
I tried setting the Chokidar ignore to match all strings that end in .xml but it looks like Chokidar ignore accepts negative regex's

Even the below example doesn't work

```
watcher = chokidar.watch(watcherFolder, { 
    ignored: /[^l]$,
    persistent: true,
    ignoreInitial: true,
    alwaysState: true}
);
```

Is there a way to do this or do I have to add the filter to the callback function?

```
watcher.on('add', function(path) {
    if (!/\.xml$/i.test(path)) { return; }
    console.log('chokidar: add: ' + path);
});
watcher.on('unlink', function(path) {
    if (!/\.xml$/i.test(path)) { return; }
    console.log('chokidar: unlink: ' + path);
});

watcher.on('change', function(path) {
    if (!/\.xml$/i.test(path)) { return; }
    console.log('chokidar: change: ' + path);
});
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`chokidar` accepts a glob pattern as first argument.
You can use it match your XML files.

```
chokidar.watch("some/directory/**/*.xml", config)
```

Comment: u should use something like path. normalize(dir_path) to avoid windows (backslash) and unix (forward slash)

Comment: How about multiple file extensions?

Comment: I just found out, we can use chokidar.watch(["some/directory/**/*.xml", "some/directory/**/*.json"], config)