# Use Chokidar for watching over files with specific extentions

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I need to add support for this feature to my app.
My current implementation is very simple:

```
            this.watcher.on("add", (pathName: string) => {
                this.sendNotifyAction(new NotifyAction(PathEvent.Add, pathName));
            }).on("change", (pathName: string) => {
                this.sendNotifyAction(new NotifyAction(PathEvent.Change, pathName));
            }).on("unlink", (pathName: string) => {
                this.sendNotifyAction(new NotifyAction(PathEvent.Delete, pathName));
            }).on("ready", () => {
                this.sendReadinessNotification();
            });
```

Now I want to have something like:

```
private acceptedFileExtensions: string[] = ['.txt', '.docx', '.xlx', ...]
```

And use this array of extensions inside Chokidar. So if the file in watched directory has extension from the list - send notification, if no - do nothing.

I saw similar question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40468608/use-chokidar-to-watch-for-specific-file-extension#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40468608/use-chokidar-to-watch-for-specific-file-extension#_=_), but it's not what I really need.

Filtering inside callback functions doesn't look good for me, but I don't see other variants. Please advise.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not something like `acceptedFileExtensions.forEach(ext => chokidar.add("**/*" + ext)`?

Comment: Or pass an array of wildcards based on those extensions to `chokidar.watch()`.

Comment: how to pass it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you @robertklep, chokidar works with arrays.
So my code looks like:

```
private buildWildcardList(path:string): string[] {
        let result: string[] = [];
        _.each(this.acceptedFileExtensions, (extension: string) => {
           result.push(path + '/**/*' + extension);
        });

       return result;
    }

let wildcardList: string[] = this.buildWildcardList(path);
this.watcher = chokidar.watch(wildcardList, watchOptions);
```

Comment: Would this be a problem if we're watching for 30 different extensions? Or would you recommend another solution?

Comment: I think it shouldn't be a problem. My solution worked with 12 extensions.