# chokidar ignore everything except xml files

Tags: javascript, regex, chokidar

When it comes to the [Chokidar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chokidar) configuration I want to setup the options. I would like to ignore everything except xml files.

```
{
    "path": "C:/... my path ...",
    "options": {
        "ignored": "everything except xml files",
        "persistent": true
    }
}
```

A possible solution would be

[Use Chokidar to watch for specific file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40468608/use-chokidar-to-watch-for-specific-file-extension)

but is there a way to set the `ignored` attribute of the JSON configuration file to "ignore everything except .xml files" instead of setting it by code?

---

I tried to go for this code

```
{
    "path": "C:/...",
    "options": {
        "ignored": "!**.xml",
        "persistent": true
    }
}




const chokidar = require('chokidar');
const { path, options } = require('../fileSystemWatcherConfiguration.json');

module.exports = eventEmitter => {
    const watcher = chokidar.watch(path, options);
}
```

but the `watcher.on('add', func)` event gets triggered on each file extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Update

It turns out it's actualy preaty simple.

```
const watcher = chokidar.watch(`${path}/**/*.xml`, options);
```

## Old answer

By analyzing the [package code](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar/blob/6e112b99f8a0aa4d3cdfd160e4f283a7eadfc50c/index.js#L375), we can see that `chokidar` uses internaly [anymatch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/anymatch) to decide if the file should be ignored.

Digging dipper `anymatch` [uses](https://github.com/micromatch/anymatch/blob/master/index.js#L3) [micromatch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/micromatch) and in examples of `micromatch` we can [see](https://www.npmjs.com/package/micromatch#matching-features) that we can use `!` at the begining to negate the math.

Comment: I'm sorry, this didn't help. No file gets ignored by the watcher now.

Comment: well yes, that's why I posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40468608/use-chokidar-to-watch-for-specific-file-extension but I was looking for a json configuration solution :)